# Копирование в буфер обмена Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Написал такой код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun Context.copyToClipboard(text: CharSequence){
        val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label",text)
        clipboard.primaryClip = clip
    }
```

Но IDE выводит ошибку на последней строке:
[image: Kotli]

Пробовал таким образом, но всё равно выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57128936) - ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: К сожалению проблема осталась. Ровно такая-же - переменная не может бы переназначена (`val cannot be reassigned`). Пробовал изменить val на var, но никак не повлияло, ошибка ровно такая - же.

Comment: То есть даже на `setPrimaryClip()` жалуется? Мне казалось, что среда разработки указывает на поле экземпляра класса...

Comment: Я добавил скриншот

Comment: Покажите ошибку с var

Comment: И исправьте заголовок, сейчас он вообще не относится к проблеме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам же студия явно пишет

```
val cannot be reassigned
```

Что это значит? А значит это то, не что ваша переменная `myClipBoard.primaryClip` является immutable т.е. неизменяемой. В Java это равносильно `final`.